# How to distribute updates to users of pre-installed paid Android App?

Tags: android, google-play

I wrote a small Android app. It is published on Google Play as two distinct versions

- a free demo version with limited features
- and the paid version without limitations

Now I have been approached by the distributor of a tablet who wants to pre-install my app on his device. Obviously, I want the owners of his product to benefit from later updates for my app.

Is there a way to pre-install the paid app on the device *and* still allow free updates to the app?

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to check that the tablet manufacturer actually has Google Play on the device. Many of the cheaper tablets do not have it.

Answer (score 4):

The pre-installed app has to be free. This comes verbatim from the [Google Play Support site](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en):

> **Unpublished Apps**
>
> Existing app users will still be able to receive app updates, even if
> you unpublish your app. If you don't want new users to find and
> download your app but still want to provide updates to your existing
> users, set your app to Unpublished in the Developer Console.
>
> **Updating system apps**
>
> The user’s system apps (including any pre-loaded apps) are shown in
> the My Apps section of the user's device in the Google Play store as
> soon as an application with the same package name is uploaded to the
> Google Play Developer Console, even if the application is unpublished.
>
> Google Play can manage updates to preloaded applications, provided the
> following conditions are met:
>
> - The preloaded app needs to be in the system partition
> - The preloaded app needs to be free
> - The preloaded app needs to be signed with the same signature as the app published in Google Play
> - The Package Name of the preloaded and updated app needs to be the same
> - The Version Code of the updated app needs to be greater than that of the preloaded app

Comment: if you preload a paid app in system partition, you will able to upgrade it, but the market will ask you to buy

Answer (score 1):

This should happen automatically as long as you use the same signing key and package name.

You can test this and verify by doing the following:

1. Install the .apk file that you will be providing to the distributor
   (lets call this 2.0).
2. Now upload 2.1 to Google Play (same signing key and package name)
3. When the user's automatic update checking runs, or when the user opens the package in Google Play, the update will be offered and work great.

The only case I have seen where this doesn't work is with cross-licensing. For example, if I license an App through the Amazon appstore, I will see updates in Google Play, but attempting to update will give me a "not paid" or "buy now" error.

Comment: But if it's a paid app, and google play  does not have a record of that person buying it, you will not be able to update.

Comment: Right, Drake, that is the problem I'm trying to solve. See comment above.

Answer (score 0):

In a common LVL implementation, if a user is not licensed, app should hang at start page and prompt user a dialog pointing them to purchase URL (can be opened via either Google Play client app or web browser).

For a paid app (LVL integrated and published via Google Play), if end user want to use it and keep receiving updates, he must use his Google account purchase it via either Google Play client app or Google Play web version.

The normal procedure to get paid app via Google Play client app is:

1. Purchase
2. Download
3. Install

> Is there a way to pre-install the paid app on the device and still allow free updates to the app?

You can send them app-pro.apk file and let them install it without purchasing it first, however, when the app is first opened and in case that license check (requires Google Play client app installed on end user's device) is failed, the purchase dialog should popped up and ask them purchase it. Once the user has purchased it and open the app again and pass license check, he can start using it normally (with ability to update).

The answer is Yes, you can let user pre-install paid app, but in order to use it normally and keep receiving updates, the user must purchase it anyway.

Comment: Indeed, that is the problem I'm trying to solve. How can I update a pre-installed app (that the device distributor paid me for) on a user's device?

Comment: As long as user has purchased and his device has Google Play installed, he can get the update via Google Play, no matter how the very first version of the app is distributed.

Comment: The user did not purchase the app. It will come pre-installed on the device he bought.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for solution for the same problem, and it appears to be impossible.
But I think I have a workaround:

Make your app free, with limited functionality, and offer advanced features ("pro" version) with in-app purchase.

For the in-app purchase version you can have a second licensing method. I'm not sure if it's allowed by Google Play terms, but technically this way you can support these two kind of users, and still have them update automatically through Google Play.